# Periodic "Connection Refused" errors when using kubectl on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kubectl

I have an AWS EC2 machine with the following specification:

| Instance Name | vCPUs | RAM | EBS-Optimized Bandwidth | Network Bandwidth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c5a.8xlarge | 32 | 64 GiB | 3.170 Gbps | 10 Gbps |

I installed Kubernetes on it with the following sequence of commands:

```
sudo kubeadm init --kubernetes-version=1.28.1
```

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
```

```
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
```

```
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.23/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Everything works fine and I am able to run `kubectl` commands, but every once in a while I start getting this error upon `kubectl` commands execution:

```
The connection to the server X.X.X.X:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

After some time or after I reboot the machine then I stop getting this error until it happens again and so forth.

I could not find any questions or info for the case where this error occurs periodically.

Any idea what is the problem? Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: did you notice any issues in the kube-apiserver or kubelet? also did you run `swapoff -a` before initializing the cluster

Comment: Thanks @Sibtain for your comment.
I tried to run the swapoff -a command (which I also saw in other places online) but it did not help.
When I try to query the kube-apiserver I got this response:
Unit kube-apiserver.service could not be found